# how can i interact with TBS6903 PCIe Card?

Tags: c++, api, qt, dll, pci-e

i am a junior programmer.

for my University project i have to write application with QT c++ to connect and interact with TBS6903 Professional DVB-S2 Dual Tuner PCIe Card.

This app should be able to :
**Ability to lock a specific frequency and give us .ts files stream.**

My main problem is that i don't know how to interact with tbs6903 card?

**It has a DLL for to do this ? it has a Api ? And tips or user manual How to work with it ?**

How can I communicate and interact with that and send my instructions in QT C++ App?

I searched in google but I did not find any solution or guidance for solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing it. Kinda hard but possible. I'm using StreamReader.lib and streamreader-utils.

Comment: Thanks u!Can you explain more?You have useful link for more explain and documents about streamreader.lib and steamreader-utils?Or related tutorial course link?

Comment: I have done it. But the files DLL and API (include .lib) is taking from my instructor. And he said that Crazycat has removed all dll files from TBS project, so right now it's really hard to find the API for TBS6903 on the internet. 

With the .lib and API files, it's really simple for call the driver and check-in parameter in card.